# PHP: will an operation in the body of foreach be called more than once?

Tags: php

foreach ( functionWithComplicatedComputationReturningAnArray() as $key => $value)

Will the above code call the function more than once?

And generally, are there rules in this regard, about PHP language constructs accepting function calls as parameters?

Thanks

Gidi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it will be called once. This:

```
foreach (functionWithComplicatedComputationReturningAnArray() as $key => $value) {
  ...
}
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
$tmp = functionWithComplicatedComputationReturningAnArray();
foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
  ...
}
```

(ignoring the fact that the second one will leak the value outside the `foreach` loop).

Comment: Thanks, what about other loops? while($someVar < func())? for($i = 0; i < func(); i++)

Comment: Here it will be called every iteration. Try to echo in function func() and you will see it.